# Howto change Pythonpath in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, osx-snow-leopard, upgrade, pythonpath

I am trying to switch from using Python 2.6.5 to using Python 3.2a2.
I am using OSX 10.6.4.
However, when I open Idle in the Python 3.2a2 folder it cannot import any of the modules I installed to Python 2.6.5.
Is there a way that I can share the same folders on Python 3.2a2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2 and Python 3 are sufficiently different that you cannot in general share modules between them. You will need new, Python-3-compatible modules instead of re-using the Python 2 ones.

(It's possible with a great deal of care to make scripts that will work in both, but it's not usually the done thing. Python 3 was designed to be the big syntax compatibility breaking version.)

Comment: I guess I will have to start over with python 3 or go back

Comment: @Peter: You should always install every module separately for each Python version. Python 3 isn't different, it's just more obvious that it won't work. See http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/newbie-hint-on-installing-python-and-its-modules-and-packages/